# Argument of type 'string | number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'

Tags: typescript

Snippet and error:

```
const methods = {
  a(value: number) {},
  b(value: string) {}
};

function callMethodWithArg(methodAndArg: { method: 'a'; arg: number; } | { method: 'b'; arg: string; }) {
  methods[methodAndArg.method](methodAndArg.arg);
}
```

> Argument of type 'string | number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.

Looks like typescript isn't intelligent enough to figure out that method `a` can only be called with a number and method `b` can only be called with a string.

Any suggestions how to type this properly?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgUygCxAEwjAvDA3gKBhgEMAKAN2IBsBXBALhjBrgCMEAnASjwF8AaQjFYVqdRtA4BLMAHMeuXvl4BufPgBmNMMChTwMYNSoBZJKjQB1KSgCCHWaUQp0tsGnuzGueOfSMAcmIAlRIHRmY2TlDeGAAfPF8XNEDWELCvGEkZWRiFIWcLCABtQtd3TwA6MrQAXSc-DwqHSuIHLjVeIA)

Comment: This is an issue I've been calling "correlated union types" in [ms/TS#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).  Currently there are only workarounds, but when TypeScript 4.6 is released, you should be able to slightly refactor this code into something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mpvZ6w) to have it work.  Do you want me to write this up as an answer?  Or am I missing something about your issue?

Comment: Thanks @jcalz. Can you do that without the `ArgMap` interface? It duplicates information that is already in `methods` variable.

Comment: I think you need a basic interface like `ArgMap` to map over; it is precisely because we give `methods` a type that distributes over such a basic type that the correlation works.  Indeed if you just don't annotate `methods` then [it fails](https://tsplay.dev/wOz7zW), even though the type is equivalent in both cases.  Do you want an answer explaining the situation?

Comment: I noticed that too and it seems rather odd. It would be great to have a more elegant solution without the `ArgMap`. Please go ahead and elaborate in an answer.

Comment: @jcalz Perhaps `infer` could help somehow?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem here is that for TypeScript up to version 4.5 there is no support for what I've been calling "correlated unions", as discussed in [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).  As you said, the compiler can't understand that method `a` can only be called with a `number` and method `b` can only be called with a string.  If we break the single line into several to inspect the types of the function and its argument, we see that each is a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types):

```
type MethodAndArg = { method: 'a'; arg: number; } | { method: 'b'; arg: string; }

function callMethodWithArg(methodAndArg: MethodAndArg) {
    const f = methods[methodAndArg.method];
    // const f: ((value: number) => void) | ((value: string) => void)
    const arg = (methodAndArg.arg);
    // const arg: string | number
    f(arg) // error!
}
```

That `f` is a union of functions, and `arg` is a union of argument types.  If `f` and `arg` weren't known to be correlated (say you got `f` from `methodAndArg` and `arg` from a different object of the same type), then of course you couldn't call the union of functions with a union of argument types.  Maybe `f` is `methods.a` and `b` is a `number`.  The compiler tracks the *types* of `f` and `arg` separately, as if they were independent.  It does not track their *source*.

---

In TypeScript 4.5 and below, the only ways I know to deal with this are to either write type safe but redundant code, like this:

```
function callMethodWithArg(methodAndArg: MethodAndArg) {
    if (methodAndArg.method === "a") {
        methods[methodAndArg.method](methodAndArg.arg);
    } else {
        methods[methodAndArg.method](methodAndArg.arg);
    }
}
```

where you use [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) to narrow `methodAndArg` to each possible subtype, and then the compiler can verify the function call in each case.

Or, you can write terse yet unsafe code, like this:

```
function callMethodWithArg(methodAndArg: MethodAndArg) {
    (methods[methodAndArg.method] as (value: number | string) => void)(
        methodAndArg.arg);
}
```

where you use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to pretend that the function can accept all `number` and `string` inputs, even though in actuality it will only accept one of those.  That is not safe because you could pass in `Math.random()<0.5 ? "a" : 1` instead of `methodAndarg.arg` and get no errors.

---

In TypeScript 4.6 and above, you should be able to use something called a "distributive object type" as introduced in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109). The idea is to come up with a mapping object type which represents a mapping from some key name to a function parameter, and then use this mapping object type to generate your other types.  The compiler will be able to "see" the correlation as long as things are properly expressed in terms of the mapping type.

Here's how it will look for your example:

```
// mapping type
interface ArgMap {
    a: number;
    b: string;
}
```

So `ArgMap` is the mapping type.  In a sense it captures the type relationship most simply (e.g., "`a` goes with `number` and `b` goes with `string`").  Now we can build your other types:

```
// map over ArgMap to get methods type
type Methods = { [K in keyof ArgMap]: (value: ArgMap[K]) => void }

const methods: Methods = {
    a(value: number) { },
    b(value: string) { }
};
```

The `Methods` type is a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over `ArgMap`, and we [annotate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) `methods` as being of this type.  This annotation is important, otherwise the link between `methods` and the type of `methodAndArg` will be broken.

Next one:

```
// map over ArgMap and index into it to get generic MethodAndArg type
type MethodAndArg<K extends keyof ArgMap = keyof ArgMap> =
    { [P in K]: { method: P, arg: ArgMap[P] } }[K]
```

Here we have a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) `MethodAndArg<K>` type, where `K` defaults to `keyof ArgMap`.  If you just write `MethodAndArg` it is the same union type as before, but if you write `MethodAndArg<"a">` it will just be the `a` method/arg pair, and `MethodArg<"b">` is just the `b` method/arg pair.  This is the "distributive object type" we need.

Finally, your `callMethodWithArg()` function:

```
// make callMethodWithArg generic in the key type of ArgMap
function callMethodWithArg<K extends keyof Methods>(methodAndArg: MethodAndArg<K>) {
    methods[methodAndArg.method](methodAndArg.arg); // okay
}
```

This function is generic in `K`, and `methodAndArg` is of type `MethodAndarg<K>`.  The correlated function call compiles with no problem, without any redundant JS code or any TS type assertions.  This is both type safe and produces terse JS code.  And when you call `callMethodWithArg()` the compiler will (in TS4.6+, remember) infer `K` properly:

```
callMethodWithArg({ method: "a", arg: 123 }); // okay
// K inferred as "a"

callMethodWithArg({ method: "b", arg: "xyz" }); // okay
// K inferred as "b"

callMethodWithArg({ method: "a", arg: "xyz" }); // error! 
// K inferred as "a", but arg is wrong
```

So this is about as good as it gets!

---

I see that you really would like something with even less work, where the compiler would be able to "see" the correlation without requiring annotating `methods`.  Maybe in some future version of TypeScript this could happen, but for now I don't think it's possible.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=4.6.0-dev.20220105#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEB5ATgSwOZIN4FgAoJEpeAe2CgBclJqALcgEyiQF48jSekQAKAG4gANgFcIALiTAxYAEYQ0ASjxIAvgBpuvEvKGiJ0mpmBZVuDTpLqA3NaTUAnjGQBZCIxYBBYM29oOJyW9EzM0gDkIBG2fIHSsgpKsepIAD5qoSyR8jFxWMbUplgpRA4AZmLA8NQYlGSiIh5ezADqGIwBWPxZ-n5d0s1hvv6BFg48FFS05Rx0nmFQANq9I10AdL0AuvbEukgA9AdklDRI5dL8BuJSMnKKKhwAfEiC5BjMqhlXwjeFxap2C83h9lBNSFMziBAnMegsfP1AutoeZdvtDsdIbQUf8MGZ0nckmhwSRyvwUaojkglGhyGgAIQOdRlQhEZmswigSCwBDIbxQKBKWgEPYkLHzFpsYIkvjXIyEh4WDTaUW8fS-eUmPHmNTsnh2Fk8ZyuJBDBGjIKZeHhJBRPI4hXJDQEkLWnL2+JILVmUocipVGp1YANERNa3tTqBOEtNaes19C3jVU8aOLFbW2NYTbWrZ8Nhy26JB4E706oGvd6ffgynirRFZilo0jslktzngaBwRBIABKEGYVWYIGAwoc4t6Uq4ydIAg1hfuSiVWhl6sMt1LS6ZuwcxvcGfrc1dLUi0ViDqLTtSGSPYXdZ89pd9-uqtXq8Ea8YjDC6qfNA1N+6JlO6IYLMv4JhsvQcOwnAAEQgLBSborW1rLHWFrZi0WzgZmyJjE2uipBAIiCsByEkBO6YxvWmFhNh6EbI2Mp6s2LJsiyVIACoAMoACzrAAbAA1EQXKdrySAACIYFq8hiLUggQCg8gAFYQDUU4OFSYAgDAMDao4LgQA4eLUEo5QSV0bi6WRuggAkC5oARaq4j6TKGqQ2k2eQiloEgVk2dQ5BIFgngSoshmuDuRkAZKh5IEsADSSB4kgADWEBOOQswBTAWyXHO0i5UlWyAsClZWBykynLQE6DKhh4yrOa4OUSS4quiq5-F6RTapuqoGlVnnHDpMBID5Sj+YE1ljcOzApX4EAAB4LUFKW0GtoW0KFwBKBg8CxcMB67tFJrxpmAA8yXLWZfhsBlWU5dNNmcA92VTVgM0vOwMqWEsAAKC1IIl+VWseSD-Zo+RFc9MAA7mqTqCVHkkF5GUhmGLRfl0IUQLtmAHaljDIA9kXIO9uXPoGb4fuGHTfoEV3Uktt2sOlmXvfGUBPDh9b1dRFpXU8SH7JRDFItsvMYY2GLjWlIBOO5Q1irTWP0z+N7ZEg8GwVDDoAIwAEwAMwaMosRUuQ8tOFDyV4uUNL9nm2sIWOqthNjUaazasHyLr0Pa0tTgAF6wWbFvHFbCu2wtDtoGgTsgGwvuwW7oafurXvhVrOt656sFB6H4eyzSdL0sDseO-NScu-7cnYjCMlIAA7rSZitkAA)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there is a cleaner solution, but this will work if you don't have too many cases:

```js
const methods = {
  a(value: number) {},
  b(value: string) {}
};

function callMethodWithArg(methodAndArg: { method: 'a'; arg: number; } | { method: 'b'; arg: string; }) {
  if (methodAndArg.method === 'a') {
    // now it knows that method has to be 'a' and arg is a number
    methods[methodAndArg.method](methodAndArg.arg)
  } else if (methodAndArg.method === 'b') {
    methods[methodAndArg.method](methodAndArg.arg)
  }
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgUygCxAEwjAvDA3gKBhgEMAKAN2IBsBXBALhjBrgCMEAnASjwF8AaQjFYVqdRtA4BLMAHMeuXvl4BufPgBmNMMChTwMYNSoBZJKjQB1KSgCCHWaUQp0tsGnuzGueOfSMAcmIAlRIHRmY2TlDeGAAfPF8XNEDWELCvGEkZWRiFISkNGCc-D3dPADpnC2wsHCCA-KIiavQIAG1Wso8HKtKAXRLktx7ZCuIHLiFYhCoIBBhC4q6Ryq7a+rSm5q6OlfLersH90fHJ6eUgA)

Answer (score 0):

My solution would be to use Type Predicates to cast the method as either Shape A or B (or however many shapes you need)

```js
type MethodA = (value: number) => void
type MethodB = (value: string) => void

type ArgA = { method: 'a'; arg: number; }
type ArgB = { method: 'b'; arg: string; }

type Methods = {
  [key: string]: MethodA | MethodB
}

const methods: Methods = {
  a(value: number) { },
  b(value: string) { }
};


function callMethodWithArg(methodAndArg: ArgA | ArgB) {
  const method = methods[methodAndArg.method]

  if (determinShape(methodAndArg)) {
    (method as MethodA)(methodAndArg.arg)
  } else {
    (method as MethodB)(methodAndArg.arg)
  }
}


/** Will cast methodAndArg as ArgA if true, else ArgB */
function determinShape(methodAndArg: ArgA | ArgB): methodAndArg is ArgA {
  return Number.isFinite(methodAndArg.arg)
}
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=31&ssc=2&pln=17&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAshwAsD2ATAglAvFAFANwEMAbAVwgC4oA7EgWwCMIAnASiwD4o8kBLFAKFCRY8ZCgBCWXIVIUoAZ2BMeVAOZtMnbn36Dw0NE1UZsAbyi1RqSgHICNgNxQCRyjQbMnAXz3DDqyTMLKxRbekdnVwUlFVVvXSFoOERUeSlTfigoAG0AawgQSkVlNQBdSmSxDAAfERSJfh9%20AGMkKkVg%20vkKkLSzTOd8YjI3OkZWKHMvABoB%20iHZIpi1NinGh11%20ADMSKmbgHjaoZuIiStQAdR5EfxxLerQqdCj-Gqh-cVWB1vbgTrEpPcxPJskDUI9nqoAHRglClXRZHhbXAoeDMWgqADKCAIkDuIQh-hYXyyWXx9WcaXO6BY5KqT38UJc6gGXigECI8mgGVJuFhlLqYk%20dPBDKMTKMLFZjU2AHoAFTyqBXIhEY4EDqwwlGAWvKBIqBKMjTdmcgxGSTy2XbXb7Q5UKCo4DorE4vFasWqSh62ofFiUD2Q-VpPU8qBMeAkJgOgByY2YUJ48gAYiprhARehPRKWV4gA)

Comment: I think it's weird, that `determineShape` would check for finite. This way, if we pass `Infinity`, it will think that it is of type `ArgB` and go to the else branch. For instance with `callMethodWithArg({ method: 'a', arg: Infinity })` it will call `methods.a(Infinity)`, but it will do so from the else branch ([Playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mAveBW))

Comment: yeah it's kinda silly to have to do this, but I can't think of a better way. isFinite vs isNaN: https://stackabuse.com/javascript-check-if-variable-is-a-number/