# Typescript generics with functions Parameters

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I'm trying to open a typescript method using generics.
There is an object with methods (the comment indicated different types of function parameters)

```
const emailTypes = {
  confirmEmail: generateConfirmEmailOptions, // { a: string, b: string;}
  restorePassword: generateRestorePasswordOptions, // { a: string, b: number;}
};
```

Type with keys of this object:

```
export type IEmailTypes = typeof emailTypes;
```

and the method itself:

```
export const getEmailOptions = <T extends keyof IEmailTypes>(emailType: T, emailData: Parameters<IEmailTypes[T]>[0]) =>
  emailTypes[emailType](emailData);
```

Now swears at `(emailData)`, I can not understand why.
I felt like I was doing the right thing. I pass the names of the key to `T`, then I take the function parameters for this key.
But no, it swears if different types.

I want to make it so that when transmitting, for example
`confirmEmail` in `emailType` , TS told me exactly what `emailData` should be

What am I doing wrong?

For clarity, I'll attach a screenshot.[image]

*methods in `emailTypes` have parameter types

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check @jcalz answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70598583/argument-of-type-string-number-is-not-assignable-to-parameter-of-type-never).

So you either sacrifice type-safety by casting, or you'll need to refactor it to help the compiler. It may look like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=2&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBA8mwEsD2A7AzlAvFArig1ikgO4oCwAUJQCYQDGANgIYBO0dqawUA5hChBZNgEAMKoAZghYBbAKIymCBnEScAXFAAUSeGk0BvKE01cWCFDwDcUAEang5y1AC+ASiwA+WPGToa9MxsUBzo3HwCQiIAShBcSGwACkxoaMQJ1Kp++tq6wDlGJlBmFtZ2mig4MraCrh6Y3lmclJQWIiwSTHTQAIIsPBgGlFAhktLyisqayUIyEO1oADygkEgSvPyCwmJjsgpKKr6cngDaAAwAusNQbPFJKWkZ06xMcwvL4BBrG5HbsXcQZKpdIsTJHdCnS6UFwtCgraAAWSYYDApSwUCMJwA0lALFB8BAQN8+gMLpodHpNCS0NiLvVGuCMDCqBRQlwoBBJgwACqfHJIlFo7BDCgjUJSPZczQRLYicQoCUTA5NdAAGig11uwASgIeIOo0s2UQg-2192BGRVaHV0KssLZ4Xm+2UVvRixxEAAHiIUNQMASietqZ4tJyDrzIJoseqw8oACLCIrU2n0jHXB1QCQodGxnl8k65iMQC4a0U3eY4FjZrOhrkJ4BMNx2ijMoA):

```
declare const generateConfirmEmailOptions: (opts: { a: string; b: string }) => void
declare const generateRestorePasswordOptions: (opts: { a: string; b: number }) => void

interface Args {
  confirmEmail: Parameters<typeof generateConfirmEmailOptions>[0]
  restorePassword: Parameters<typeof generateRestorePasswordOptions>[0]
}

type Mapping = { [K in keyof Args]: (opts: Args[K]) => void }

const emailTypes: Mapping = {
  confirmEmail: generateConfirmEmailOptions, 
  restorePassword: generateRestorePasswordOptions, 
};

const getEmailOptions = <K extends keyof Args>(emailType: K, emailData: Args[K]) => {
  const fn = emailTypes[emailType] 
  return fn(emailData);
}
```

Yes, it's a bit unfortunate that you have to duplicate some code, but apparently right now is the only 100% type-safe way to do it. Let's see what future versions of TypeScript bring.

Comment: Thanks for the example, now I understand how it works!