# TypeScript is weirdly joining types

Tags: typescript

Imagine I have 2 different functions that I want to call depending on the passed function name. Also, I want to add type annotations for the function parameters.

Minimal example:

```js
const a = (options: { o1: number }) => {}
const b = (options: { o2: string }) => {}

const functions = { a, b }

type A = {
  name: 'a'
  options: Parameters<typeof a>[0]
}
type B = {
  name: 'b'
  options: Parameters<typeof b>[0]
}

type Data = A | B

(data: Data) => {
  functions[data.name](data.options)
}
```

But TypeScript won't allow passing `data.options`:

```
TS2345: Argument of type '{ o1: number; } | { o2: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ o1: number; } & { o2: string; }'.   Type '{ o1: number; }' is not assignable to type '{ o1: number; } & { o2: string; }'.     Property 'o2' is missing in type '{ o1: number; }' but required in type '{ o2: string; }'.
```

Looks like TypeScript transforms

```js
type Data = A | B
```

into

```js
type Data = {
  name: 'a' | 'b'
  options: Parameters<typeof a>[0] | Parameters<typeof b>[0]
}
```

which seems incorrect for me

Comment: It's not transforming `A | B` into that, but `functions[data.name]` has type `((options: { o1: number }) => {}) | ((options: { o2: string }) => {})`, which is equivalent to `((options: { o1: number } & { o2: string }) => {})`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Argument of type 'string | number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70598583/argument-of-type-string-number-is-not-assignable-to-parameter-of-type-never)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is one I call "correlated union types".  This was reported in [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) and has been addressed via [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109), which advises a certain kind of refactoring to help the compiler understand what you're doing.

---

In general, if you have a function `f` and an argument `x`, both of which are of [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) types, like this:

```
declare const f: ((options: { o1: number }) => void) | ((options: { o2: string }) => void)
declare const x: { o1: number } | { o2: string }
```

then it is not safe to call the function using that argument, and the TypeScript compiler generates an error telling you this:

```
f(x); // error!
// Argument of type '{ o1: number; } | { o2: string; }' is not assignable to 
// parameter of type '{ o1: number; } & { o2: string; }'.
```

That error message might be confusing, but it's just saying that the argument union doesn't work; the only thing it knows would work would be an argument [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types), as per [the support for calling union types introduced in TS3.3](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-3.html#improved-behavior-for-calling-union-types) and implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#29011](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29011).

It makes sense that this would be an error, since for all the compiler knows, `f` might be of type `(options: { o1: number }) => void)` while `x` is of type `{ o2: string }`.  That is, they might be mismatched.

---

Now, in your code you're doing this:

```
const f = functions[data.name];
const x = data.options;
f(x); // same error!
```

The compiler produces the same error as above and for the same reason: `f` and `x` are both of union types, and for all the compiler knows, they might be mismatched. But the compiler doesn't realize that the types of `f` and `x` are *correlated* to each other.  They both depend on the type of `data` in such a way as to make a mismatch impossible.

This is effectively a limitation of TypeScript.  If you leave `f` and `x` of union types, the compiler will not be able to see any correlation between them.

---

The refactoring recommended in microsoft/TypeScript#47109 is to make your function [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) instead of a union, and pass it an argument of a corresponding generic type.  In order for this to work, the function and argument types must be curated quite carefully.

First, we can create a `DataMap` mapping interface which represents a basic key-value relationship from which we can build your other types:

```
interface DataMap {
  a: { o1: number },
  b: { o2: string }
};
```

Then, we can [annotate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) your `functions` variable as a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) which explicitly iterates over the key and value types of `DataMap`:

```
const a = (options: { o1: number }) => { }
const b = (options: { o2: string }) => { }   
const functions: { [K in keyof DataMap]: (options: DataMap[K]) => void } =
  { a, b }
```

Instead of `Data` being a straight union of hardcoded `A` and `B`, we can rewrite `Data` as a generic *distributive object type* (which, as mentioned in ms/TS#47109, is a mapped type into which we immediately [index](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html):

```
type Data<K extends keyof DataMap = keyof DataMap> =
  { [P in K]: { name: P, options: DataMap[P] } }[K]
```

From this we can define `A` or `B` if you want:

```
type A = Data<"a">
type B = Data<"b">
```

And if you want, you can use the `Data` type without a type argument (thanks to its [generic default](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults)) and see that it's the same type as your version:

```
type D = Data
/* type D = {
    name: "a"; options: { o1: number; };
} | {
    name: "b"; options: { o2: string; };
} */
```

And *now* we can write your function; instead of accepting `Data`, we accept `Data<K>` for generic `K`:

```
<K extends keyof DataMap>(data: Data<K>) => {
  functions[data.name](data.options); // okay
}
```

Yay, no compiler error!  That works because the compiler sees the types of `functions[data.name]` and `data.options` as appropriately related generics:

```
<K extends keyof DataMap>(data: Data<K>) => {
  const f: (options: DataMap[K]) => void = functions[data.name];
  const x: DataMap[K] = data.options;
  f(x); // okay
}
```

You can see that the argument `x` is of type `DataMap[K]`, and the function `f` is of type `(options: DataMap[K]) => void`.  So the argument is seen to be exactly the type that the function accepts, and there is no longer a compiler error.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.4#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEB5ATgSwOZIN4Cgkl4B7YKAFyRCQF4kAKEmCjMqALjyRIEYvgAVzAAjCGiQBfAJR0AfN0mFi7KiLqNmrdl1w8ATF0qZgOGfMX5lpclQBmg4PG3kNekABok6pcooBPGGQAQTdlIlBILgByEGjwnhY2ci4ABRA0cAgKcSgAHgCgkjtqOQBtAAYAXWUlIkLkACEwogismJF41sSXTiR0zMgctHyG4u9y6tqresDkABEQChp6UIAfJEaZxgATJZAuReXZWgUCbptKJBL6Bydesr3lgDpIiCqAbgSAem+VW2uXAYTCSOm4fAEwjEEnMpyQADcSBgdrINsCtMk+noSIYkMYMKYpCcFIjkdIEpcqAAPDRPEDPDHsL7dX7-K5U3Q8fhIISicRSJAbbG4-GEuqtOwMKnSD5IVniNAkNAAQh+f2CaCwwggwCo4waSGi2O5vOhsskgvBIooJiw5uiSAwUB5JCoICgUGwoBEABtkBQSEg1Ug4INsvz9XNDcbIXy0OakAAyK1GG0Eu1SaLPab4JRvWAIZAAMQwNPObLdGhBvU5EJ5UP5sLOUmsqm8VcZKRTeLTYuJlmUBOGdkLSCOIAAsiAYHgEgdwSaGzCPAkRLXrbaW0RJF9WwC7s5MZyygBpR3AJAAawg-nG46nMCqQM7fXv09PVX7pJ2AtoCXcXg+NsBrjnkZ4QFSOTADszrXreJRvjO9BwXe+wPgof7dHoZSpOeSAnk+3BvGkXgvocaHvqkVQCpIH7AVG8waOOyjfAAVEgIEtN0PLtEgABEIB8bKZELrGZpSMyApCgkbRRPxIhCT0R7dqKGY7rUSCsd89FBEgoT0KBAl8XIfhRs0Bn7HkfEKSZyhgUgEFQTBV43qhyzoQwdLkcsYFyP25ZEJSgKaKCXaIR+X5Ij+tyOIe7CPPsrxZJ8FJthyY4UTAH60olL6SUQB4PHSSWQFUnm5aFUAynKfwkJeID+DmkhAA)